# Making UIView appear and disappear with swipe up and swipe down - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swipe

I am trying to make a project in swift and am very new to the language.

I am trying to make a UIView appear and disappear with swipe up and swipe down on the screen. I am currently using a struct to store the instance of the view in order to be able to make changes with both the swipeUp() and swipeDown() methods.

When i try to access this.view.bounds.height it tells me "instance member view cannot be used on type SecondViewController"

Below is my code

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit




class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

let label = UILabel()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeUp")
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeDown")
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)


}

struct myVars{

    let v = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: this.view.bounds.height / 2, width: this.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height / 2))

}


func swipeUp(){

    if myVars.v.isDescendantOfView(self) {

        myVars.v.isHidden = false

    }

    else {
        self.view.addSubview(myVars.v)
    }



}

func swipeDown(){
    myVars.v.isHidden = true
}




}
```

Can you please, either tell me what is wrong with my code or let me know if there is a better way to do this altogether?

Comment: Did you add your myVars.v to any view in the View Hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Just check Replace you code With below code it works. 
On place of  #selector(ViewController.swipeUp) put name of your viewController

```
let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeUp))
            swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)



let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swipeDown))
                swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
                self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```